# how do I mark one row and store its particular value in Hive using standard Query or using UDF?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, udf

I need to write a query in Hive or define a function that needs to do the followings:

The dataset:

```
Student || Time    || ComuputerPool
-------------------------------------
  A     ||  9:15AM ||  Pool1.Machine2
-------------------------------------
  A     ||  9:45AM ||  Pool1.Machine7
-------------------------------------
  A     ||  10:15AM||  Pool1.Machine9
-------------------------------------
  A     ||  11:00AM||  Pool2.Machine2
-------------------------------------
  A     ||  12:05  ||  Pool2.Machine3
-------------------------------------
  A     ||  12:40  ||  Pool3.Machine5
------------------------------------- 
  A     ||  13:10  ||  Pool1.Machine3
-------------------------------------
  A     ||  13:50  ||  Pool1.Machine10
-------------------------------------
  B   ..........................
```

so now the query should find out how long a particular student has spent in a particular computer pool by calculating the difference of when he first used a machine in a pool and when he first start using a machine in another pool. So this example the time he spent would be the difference of :
    11:00AM - 9:15AM = 1Hour45Mins

My question here is how am I going to mark the first use in one store time value and use it later when I find the next pool data.

Comment: Your question seems to be explicitly about Hive, so I removed the mysql tag.

Answer (score 1):

Hive supports `row_number()`, so you can use a trick for grouping sequential values.  The difference between two row numbers defines a group, which can then be used for aggregation.  The resulting query looks like:

```
select student, grp, min(time), max(time)
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by student order by time) -
              row_number() over (partition by student, computerpool order by time)
             ) as grp
      from dataset t
     ) t
group by student, grp, computerpool;
```

EDIT:

Your question is about *pools* not *machines*.  So, you only care about the part before the period, presumably.  (By the way, you should store this information in separate columns).

```
select student, substr(computerpool, 1, 6), min(time), max(time)
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by student order by time) -
              row_number() over (partition by student, substr(computerpool, 1, 6) order by time)
             ) as grp
      from dataset t
     ) t
group by student, grp, substr(computerpool, 1, 6);
```

Comment: its grouping by pools even though they were in different time, because it should consider the pool as different as soon as he lease it and consider next visit as new group

Comment: @dhssa . . . I think that is what this query does.

Comment: I ran it and it grouped the pools into one group regardless its time frame and numbered them from 1,2,.. . Expected: 1.visit of Pool1 the number 1,2,.. and second visit Pool1 again from 1, 2, ...

Comment: question is edited: extra two rows are added so the query should not group first Pool1 and second Pool1 or should not number them all together rather separately